# calculating averages from text file c#

Tags: c#, average

i need help on how to make the program display the average of all the the priced combined at the end

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] hours = new int[31];
    const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.5M;
    const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00M;
    decimal pay;
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader("hours.txt");
    line = fileSR.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        hours[counter] = int.Parse(line);
        counter = counter + 1;
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();
    }
    fileSR.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("hours     pay");
    for (int i = 0; i < hours.Length; i++)
    {
        pay = Math.Min(hours[i] * HOURLY_RATE, MAX_FEE);
        Console.WriteLine("{0,4} {1,10}", hours[i], pay.ToString("C"));
    }
    Console.ReadKey();




}
```

}
}

i am a bit stuck on how to get it to display all the results then add the average at the bottom of the application

Comment: Kindly elaborate on what your code is trying to do

Comment: so basically the code is displaying the hours from the text file along with the prices, then i would like it to calculate the average of all the prices

Comment: Try doing this `decimal result = Math.Min(File.ReadLines("hours.txt").Select(x => decimal.Parse(x)).Average() * HOURLY_RATE, MAX_FEE);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer you to use a class like the following to handle all your data from the file:

```
public class wages
{
    const decimal HOURLY_RATE = 2.5M;
    const decimal MAX_FEE = 20.00M;
    private int _WorkingHour;

    public int WorkingHour
    {
        get { return _WorkingHour; }
        set
        {
            _WorkingHour = value;
            _AmountToPay = Math.Min(value * HOURLY_RATE, MAX_FEE);
        }
    }
    private decimal _AmountToPay;

    public decimal AmountToPay
    {
        get { return _AmountToPay; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0,4} {1,10}", WorkingHour, AmountToPay.ToString("C"));
    }
}
```

Then Create a List of class to store the details from the file, display them and calculate the sum and average like the following:

```
var LinesInFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("hours.txt");
List<wages> wagesList = new List<wages>();
foreach (string line in LinesInFile)
{
    wagesList.Add(new wages() { WorkingHour = int.Parse(line) });
}

// Display the details
Console.WriteLine("hours     pay");
foreach (wages wage in wagesList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(wage.ToString());// overrided method will give you the formated string
}
Console.WriteLine("Average Pay : {0}", wagesList.Average(x => x.AmountToPay));
```

If you are still wanted to go with your code, then you have to declare a variable to keep the sum of pay and then get the average based on that value, I think you have to follow the code below:

```
Console.WriteLine("hours     pay");
decimal sumOfPay = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < hours.Length; i++)
{
    pay = Math.Min(hours[i] * HOURLY_RATE, MAX_FEE);
    sumOfPay += pay;
    Console.WriteLine("{0,4} {1,10}", hours[i], pay.ToString("C"));
}
Console.WriteLine("Average Pay : {0}", sumOfPay / hours.Length );
```

Comment: No problems, happy to help you, please let me know if it helps

Comment: so at the moment i am just trying to stick with using arrays, similar to what i had on my original code, as i am still trying to learn them, would there be a way to find the average using the original code i used?

Comment: bottom one worked fine, thankyou will look into using classes in the future